# Python OpenID error: No matching endpoint found after discovering [uri]

Tags: openid, mod-python

I'm getting a "No matching endpoint found after discovering [openid identifier]" error when I invoke complete() method of the consumer.

The funny thing is that out of the four OpenID providers I have tested, this behavior is observed only with LiveJournal. What steps can you suggest to investigate and fix the problem?

```
store = FileOpenIDStore("/path/to/store")

def login(req, uri):
    req.content_type = "text/html"
    session = Session.Session(req)
    consumer = Consumer(session, store)
    auth = consumer.begin(uri)
    util.redirect(req, auth.redirectURL("http://example.com", "http://example.com/authtest.py?sid=" + session.id()))
    return

def index(req, sid):
    req.content_type = "text/html"
    c = Consumer(Session.Session(req, sid), store)
    args = req.args.split("&")
    arg_dict = {}
    for i in range(0, len(args)):
        x, y = args[i].split("=")
        arg_dict[x] = unquote(y)
    v = c.complete(arg_dict, "http://example.com/authtest.py?" + req.args)
    if v.status == 'failure':
        return v.message
    else:
        return v.status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any glaring error in your code, but here are some steps to investigate:

- Is there any output from `oidutil.log`?  It logs to stderr by default, but you can override it to log to somewhere else if your web server doesn't let you see stderr.
- Capture all requests/responses.  You can use something like [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966)  to get the indirect request/response passed through the browser, and feed it to `contrib/openid-parse` from the python-openid distribution to make it more something readable.
- Does the example consumer in the python-openid source distribution work with your LJ identifier?  If so, what are the differences in request/response between the example and your code?
- Does your LJ identifier have any punctuation in it?
- Is LJ the only OpenID version 1.x provider you're testing against?  (Probably.  Hopefully there aren't too many left.)
- Your argument parsing could use `urlparse.parse_qs`, but I'm not sure that's really a problem.  (And parse_qs returns {key: [list-of-values]}, whereas `Consumer.complete` expects {key: single-value}, so you have to map one to the other.)

Comment: Using oidutil.log I have found out that the openID library doesn't check OpenID 1.0, which LJ appears to use; it only checks 1.1 despite the fact that the code for processing 1.0 seems to be there. Investigating.

Comment: I fixed it. As per http://trac.openidenabled.com/trac/ticket/162, in consumer.py the line 986 should look like `except (DiscoveryFailure, TypeURIMismatch):`, because the _discoverAndVerify method raises DiscoveryFailure when a mismatch occurs. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Huh.  cygnus closed that ticket as `worksforme`.  And it works for me too.  I wonder what's going on there.